# Returning a string where for every character in the original there are three characters

Tags: python

The solution to this problem has already been provided, however what I'm curious to know is *why my solution doesn't work*, as the logic makes perfect sense to me and I can't understand why the output is not correct.

Problem:

> Given a string, return a string where for every character in the
> original there are three characters.
>
> ```
> >>> paper_doll('Hello') 
> 'HHHeeellllllooo'
> ```

My solution:

```
def paper_doll(text):
    result = ''
    for letter in text:
        tripled_letter = letter*3
        result += result + tripled_letter
    return result
```

When I run the code I get 'HHHHHHeeeHHHHHHeeelllHHHHHHeeeHHHHHHeeellllllHHHHHHeeeHHHHHHeeelllHHHHHHeeeHHHHHHeeellllllooo' instead of 'HHHeeellllllooo'. I can't understand what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the `tripled_letter` to result, not the sum of `result` and `tripled_letter`

```py
def paper_doll(text:str)->str:
    result = ''
    for letter in text:
        tripled_letter = letter*3
        result += tripled_letter
    return result
```

You could use list comprehension to make it more compact:

```py
def paper_doll(text:str)->str:
    return ''.join([char*3 for char in text])
```

**Word of explanation:**

The syntax:

```py
x += x
```

is equivalent to:

```py
x = x+x
```

So in your case:

```py
result += result + letter*3
```

is equivalent to:

```
result = result+result+letter*3
```

Which is not what you want in this case, since the contcatenated `result` is "doubled" if you will.

Answer (score 1):

1. Please use text formatting on a post so that people can read your question properly (especially code) like so:

   ```py
   def paper_doll(text):
       result = '' 
       for letter in text: 
           tripled_letter = letter*3 
           result += result + tripled_letter

       return result
   ```
2. You used the operator += but it wasn't needed, which is why you were doing the operation twice. Use one of the following instead:

   ```py
       result = result + tripled_letter
   ```

   or

   ```py
       result += tripled_letter
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
result += result + tripled_letter
```

you should either use just concatenation like so

```
result = result + tripled_letter
```

xor just extended addition like so

```
result += tripled_letter
```

but definitely not both at same time.

Answer (score 0):

```
def paper_doll(text):
    result = ''
    for letter in text:
        tripled_letter = letter*3  # Trippled here
        result += tripled_letter  # Added here
    return result
```

The resulting variable is updated and again re-added at each iteration.